# Upgrading Ionic 3 - Ionic 4 CSS copy over issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I'm working on updating an Ionic 3 application to Ionic 4. I'm having an issue with the app css not working. I copied everything within app.scss from the original application to global.scss in the new application.

When I load up the first page of the app it looks nothing like the original application. I thought this part was more or less copy/paste but I may be wrong. One thing I experimented with was a line of css I have that looks like:

```
ion-input.input {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

and changed it to

```
ion-input {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

The new application then seems to take the border into account. Is there some major css changes needed in this conversion? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are major changes. Now that Ionic 4 is based on web components the insides of them are encapsulated.

This is so they can be dropped into any page and look how the developer expects it to look, rather than being messed up by the pages styles.

The web components expose certain settings that can be styled. These are listed at the end of each documentation page. For example with ion-input:

[ion-input - custom css properties - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#css-custom-properties)

Comment: have any suggestions on how to approach the change? Scrap the current CSS or is there a simpler way of making the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for the [border](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/17767#issuecomment-481734515), and here is a solution for [margin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities). Unfortunately the reason this has to be changed in Ionic 4 is because the Shadow DOM is now being implemented. [Here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-ionic-and-why-its-awesome/) is more info on that. Cheers :)

Comment: do you have any experience in doing this? Would it be better to basically start from scratch on the css or try to convert lots of old css to use the new way?

Comment: Well hopefully you've got global css that makes life a little easier. What I did was put the updated css in the app.scss filefor global classes and id's. That would be your best bet. Unfortunately you would have to still go through each scss pages and update the styles.